# Which observer to use during checkout order lock?

Tags: orders, inventory, event-observer, order-status

We're currently searching for an observer to use while a submitted order is locked during the checkout process. We've found that

```
Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::lockOrderInventoryData
```

is deprecated since 1.4, so is there any observer that one can use to check things while the order/products are locked in the DB?

Does Magento happen to work with InnoDB's transactions since 1.4 so we could use any checkout_* observer there?

Many thanks!

Comment: It would be highly beneficial if you gave us a bit of context for what you are trying to accomplish in the observer.

Comment: Hey davidalger, we have installed the Magento extension "Multi-Location Inventory" which adds the possibility to set an inventory qty on a website basis. During/After checkout we need to submit the quote/cart to an external server, and we need to determine which stock inventory (admin store stock or website stock) the products need to be substracted from. So for high-traffic stores we'd like to do that check while the products are locked during the process.

Comment: How about reserving the inventory quantity when adding to cart?

Answer (score 2):

I think a good place to start looking would be in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote`. Here you will find a function `submitOrder` which converts a quote into an order.

It is using the `core/resource_transaction` when performing the convert of a quote to an order and appears to have some events that could help you out.

1. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`
2. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`
3. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure`
4. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after`

Each of these events give you the order and quote objects and so you should be able to work out which state you are in and update the inventory as required.